# Can't open the playstore page with Play Store App with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I'm developing an Android app with Apache Cordova(3.4.1-0.1.0).

I would like to set an event that opens an app page with the "App Store" app, but the market link is not working as I require. An app page will open with "App Store" app, but the "App Store" app will appear **over my app view**. I need to open the "App Store" with **original "App Store" view**.

Below code is a simplified sample code of index.html in my app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    var url = "market://details?id=com.facebook.katana"; // facebook app.
    alert('open ' + url);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body><h1>market link test</h1></body>
</html>
```

I've tested the same code with `inappblowser` plugin, as well, and neither work well. DOes anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

If you put  `window.open(url, '_system');`

it wont shows any dialog window, directly opens in device's 'Google Play' app.

Comment: Why didn't @user2642254 mark any answer, and especially yours, as correct?

Answer (score 2):

With cordova, you can open the playstore with:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    var url = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"; // facebook app.
    alert('open ' + url);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}, false);
```

You can use the `market://<address>` if you are in a native android application, but with Cordova, you're writing your code in html5, the reference could be with an HTTP Request.
Other thing, is try use `https://` in your url, but not is totally necessary, but is a good idea use it.

Comment: if use `http://` with inappblowser, intent dialog is shown. and there are 'Blowser' app and 'App Store' app. But if I choice 'App Store' app, the app view appear over my app view, not original 'App Store' view.